# no sound in FrameRecorder / FFmpegFrameRecorder output file

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

this is the code i'm using to resize a video in android with JavaCV and ffmpeg -

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FmpegFrameGrabber("/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/VIDEO0066.mp4"); 
        grabber.start();

        int w = (int)grabber.getImageWidth()/2;
        int h = (int)grabber.getImageHeight()/2;        

        if (w%2 != 0) w=w-1;
        if (h%2 != 0) h=h-1;

        FrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("/sdcard/DCIM/output.mov", w, h ,grabber.getAudioChannels());

        recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
        recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
        recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE); 
        recorder.start(); 

        Frame frame = null;
        while ((frame = grabber.grabFrame()) != null)
        {
            IplImage source = frame.image;
            if (source!=null)
            {
            IplImage destination = cvCreateImage(cvSize(w , h), source.depth(), source.nChannels() );
            cvResize(source, destination);
            frame.image = destination;
            recorder.record(frame);

            }
        }
```

If i use the original width and height than the video is with sound, but when i use w/2 and h/2 the output file is without sound.
Please advise.

Comment: hi may i see ur import block in ur class..

Comment: hi i want to add audio(mp3) file in my video which is generated from set of images using ffmpegframerecorder.do u have any idea?

Comment: This should be fixed in newer versions of JavaCV. Do you still have that issue?

Comment: @SamuelAudet is there any possibilty to play the video using rtmp service url in videoview??

Comment: @N.V.R Sure, FFmpeg accepts RTMP URLs and then we can draw the images in whatever way we wish.